# Vue.js How to pass params from one component to another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on adding a refresh button. How to do I pass the 1 in component A to component B? I tried adding `return NameAdmin.methods.refreshPage(1);` but it isn't being passed. I can see the `refresh adminName Page` in the console.log.

here is component A: NameAdmin

```js
methods: {

refreshPage()  // refreshPage(1) doesn't work
        {
            console.log('refresh adminName Page');
            this.getData(1);
        },
}
```

here is component B

```js
import NameAdmin from "./NameAdmin";

Computed: {
        refreshAction()
        {
            switch (this.$route.name) {
                case "office":
                    return 'buildingData';
                case "audienceadmin":
                    return NameAdmin.methods.refreshPage();
                case "testing":
                    return null;
            }
            return null;
            
        },
         refreshPage()
        {
            if (!this.refreshAction) return;
            if(typeof this.refreshAction === "function") this.refreshAction();
            else this.$store.dispatch(this.refreshAction);
        },
    },
}
```

```html
<template>
 <refresh-button
          id="refresh-button"
          :class="refresh-style"
          @on-refresh="refreshPage"
        />
</template>
```

how can I fix my code or how should I code this differently, please let me know!
Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I'd be looking into some sort of "state management" like vuex for vue2 or pinia for vue3

Comment: `How to do I pass the 1 in component A to component B? ` what exactly needs to be passed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 2 of those components are not related to each other (not parent-child relation etc), you will have to use a state management like an user has stated.

And since you are using vue2, you have to use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org)

A common example of a `state management` usage is shopping cart on E-commerce websites.

For example I went to **Shop A**, add **XYZ product** on my shopping cart, then go to **Shop B**, add **LMN product** to my shopping cart. When i view the cart, it will contain **both XYZ product and LMN product**. That's thanks to `state management` like `vuex` provides.

Read the docs for further information of how this works because it require setup.

I hope this helps!